# iPhone App - Remote Database - Suggestions

Tags: iphone, sql, database

What are the best suggestions for developing an app which uses data stored remotely in a database? Are there any frameworks out there?

The reason I want to use a remote database is because I want a web app to communicate with data input into the iphone. So I need some centralised data storage..

I couldn't find much online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think web services might be a better fit than trying to access data stored remotely in a database.  Use the web service as a facade over the data.

Comment: Ok great- are there any tutorials out there?

Comment: There are several tutorials, some of which are mentioned on this site, depending on programming language.  If you're using an iPhone for communication, a JSON or POX (plain old xml) style web service might be easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to communicate with server.

1) Using web services as tjg184 suggested

2) Using API, API is an interface that will interact with your database and return data in XML/JSON format to device, this API can be developed in any language PHP, JAVA, C#.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Webservices can be SOAP or REST, while API can be a simple page with returns response. For example, login.php, where I pass username and password in POST method of request and which returns me TRUE/FALSE as response, this way is not webservice, it is called API

Comment: SOAP and REST are APIs. Google SOAP Search API: http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/ Facebook REST API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: Check the difference between API and Webservices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808421/api-vs-webservice, webservice is a API, but all APIs can not be webservices...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the service/framework Parse. It is VERY easy to get up and running and is free up to certain data and access limits. I just wrote a blog post about them after I implemented their service into my new app. [Parse, The Best Backend for iPhone SDK](http://www.subtorioussound.com/1/post/2012/05/parse-the-best-backend-for-iphone-sdk.html)