# Can this be considered an API?

Tags: database, interface

If I have an online database containing data about people (name, age, country etc), and then I create a page that displays information of it, and save it as: mywebsite.com/api/get_person_information/person_id
This page would simply display a serialized array (PHP) with information of a table's row (which primary key value should be replaced in 'person_id'). Could that be considered an Web API?

Comment: It could, but the question is why would this matter?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808421/api-vs-webservice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web API is anything that lets other people make an application reusing components of your application or your data. That would make exposing your data in a machine-readable way an API.

(You might want to use a more popular format to expose said data instead of PHP's variable dump syntax.)