# What is the difference between a web API and a web service?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, terminology

Is there any difference between a **web API** and a **web service** ? Or are they one and the same ?

Comment: See also: [API vs. Webservice \[closed\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808421)

Comment: See also programmers.SE: [Difference between Web API and Web Service?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/38691)

Comment: An API is the published interface, while the service is the implementation running in the backend.

Comment: Please read answers with caution. Some of them either outdated or invalid

Comment: just adding one more brilliant explanation -  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-web-services-and-API

Answer (score 75, accepted):

A web service typically offers a [WSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) from which you can create client stubs automatically. Web Services are based on the [SOAP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP).
ASP.NET Web API is a newer Microsoft framework which helps you to build [REST based interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Uniform_interface). The response can be either JSON or XML, but there is no way to generate clients automatically because Web API does not offer a service description like the WSDL from Web Services.
So it depends on your requirements which one of the techniques you want to use. Perhaps even [WCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) fits your requirements better, just look at the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Web services are NOT necessarily based on the SOAP protocol.

Comment: technically outdated answer

Comment: "ASP.NET Web API" is a Microsoft framework, not "Web API" itself.

Comment: outdated answer, visit this link https://microsoft-techies.blogspot.com/2014/03/difference-between-api-and-web-service.html

Answer (score 42):

The basic difference between Web Services and Web APIs

Web Service:

1) It is a SOAP-based service and returns data as XML.

2) It only supports the HTTP protocol.

3) It is not open source but can be used by any client that understands XML.

5) It requires a SOAP protocol to receive and send data over the network, so it is not a light-weight architecture.

Web API:

1) A Web API is an HTTP based service and returns JSON or XML data by default.

2) It supports the HTTP protocol.

3) It can be hosted within an application or IIS.

4) It is open source and it can be used by any client that understands JSON or XML.

5) It has light-weight architecture and good for devices which have limited bandwidth, like mobile devices.

Comment: A web service can be hosted on lots of places, not only IIS

Comment: Practically all the points are wrong. I can't understand how 40 users could have up-voted.

Comment: @horcrux I agree.  A Web Service is not necessary a SOAP based service.

Comment: the most confusing answer I  have ever seen.

Answer (score 25):

[API vs Web Service](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-api-and-web-service/)

Just pasted the summary of the linked article:

> Summary:
>
> 1. All Web services are APIs but all APIs are not Web services.
> 2. Web services might not perform all the operations that an API would perform.
> 3. A Web service uses only three styles of use: SOAP, REST and XML-RPC for
>      communication whereas API may use any style for communication.
> 4. A Web service always needs a network for its operation whereas an API doesn’t need a network for its operation.
> 5. An API facilitates interfacing directly with an application whereas a Web service is a ...

Read more: Difference Between API and Web Service | Difference Between | API vs Web Service http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-api-and-web-service/#ixzz3e3WxplAv

See the above link for the complete answer.

Comment: But, question is about difference between WebAPI and WebService, not "API"

Comment: Furthermore, the point 3 is not correct. It is misleading, and it just helps to make confusion about the "SOAP vs. REST" topic.

Answer (score 10):

for more detail visit this link
[image: Diagram]

Comment: why?
from this image it seems that SOAP web services cannot be used on smartphones... or even on desktops?
really?  someone is forcing you to read JSON instead of XML on those platforms?

Comment: if reading xml it does not mean it SOAP base service REST also support Command Separated Value (CSV), JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) and Really Simple Syndication (RSS).

Answer (score 8):

A Web Service if you want is a Web API. Specifically Web API usually means RESTful (HTTP based) web service and Web Service usually means SOAP+WSDL (+HTTP or SMTP or JMS..).

Tipically RESTful web services are opposed to Web Services (WSDL,SOAP) but recently it has been introduced the term RESTful Web services (with uppercase 'W') that means RESTful+WSDL+SOAP..

Check out this chart for differences among the three concepts:
http://www2.mokabyte.it/cms/figureproviderservlet?figureId=IUS-6NS-OBV_7f000001_19624184_5621ef4e--Fig02.jpg

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Web service is absolutely the same as Web API - just a bit more restricted in terms of underlying data format. Both use HTTP protocol and both allows to create RESTful services.
And don't forget for other protocols like JSON-RPC - maybe they fit better.

Comment: Not "absolutely the same" if there are restrictions now are they?

Answer (score 2):

API and Web service serve as a means of communication.

The only difference is that a **Web service facilitates interaction between two machines over a network. An API acts as an interface between two different applications so that they can communicate with each other**. 
*An API is a method by which third-party vendors can write programs that interface easily with other programs. 
A Web service is designed to have an interface that is depicted in a machine-processable format usually specified in Web Service Description Language (WSDL)*

**All Web services are APIs but not all APIs are Web services.**

**A Web service is merely an API wrapped in HTTP.**

---

This [here](https://www.guru99.com/api-vs-web-service-difference.html) article provides good knowledge regarding web service and API.

Answer (score 2):

1. Web service is a collection of open source protocols and standards used for exchanging data between systems
   or applications whereas API is a software interface that allows two applications to interact with each other
   without any user involvement.
2. Web service is used for REST, SOAP and XML-RPC for communication while API is used for any style of communication.
3. Web service supports only HTTP protocol whereas API supports HTTP/HTTPS protocol.
4. Web service supports XML while API supports XML and JSON.
5. All Web services are APIs but all APIs are not web services.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of ASP.Net a Web API is a Controller whose base class is [ApiController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and does not use Views.
A Web Service is a class derived from [WebService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webservice?view=netframework-4.7.2) and has automatic WSDL generation.  By default it is a SOAP api, but you can also use JSON by adding a [ScriptServiceAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score -1):

Well, TMK may be right in the Microsoft world, but in world of all software including Java/Python/etc, I believe that there is no difference.  They're the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

### Difference between Web Service and Web API nicely explained here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38691/difference-between-web-api-and-web-service

### Text from the link:

Web Services - that's standard defined by W3C, so they can be accessed semi-automatically or automatically (WSDL / UDDI). The whole thing is based on XML, so anyone can call it. And every aspect of the service is very well defined. There's parameters description standard, parameter passing standard, response standard, discovery standard, etc. etc. You could probably write 2000 pages book that'd describe the standard. There are even some "additional" standards for doing "standard" things, like authentication.

Despite the fact that automatic invoking and discovery is barely working because clients are rather poor, and you have no real guarantee that any service can be called from any client.

Web API is typically done as HTTP/REST, nothing is defined, output can be for eg. JSON/XML, input can be XML/JSON/or plain data. There are no standards for anything => no automatic calling and discovery. You can provide some description in text file or PDF, you can return the data in Windows-1250 instead of unicode, etc. For describing the standard it'd be 2 pages brochure with some simple info and you'll define everything else.

Web is switching towards Web API / REST. Web Services are really no better than Web API. Very complicated to develop and they eat much more resources (bandwidth and RAM)... and because of all data conversions (REQUEST->XML->DATA->RESPONSE->XML->VALIDATION->CONVERSION->DATA) are very slow.

Eg. In WebAPI you can pack the data, send it compressed and un-compress+un-pack on the client. In SOAP you could only compress HTML request.

Answer (score -2):

**All WebServices is API but all API is not WebServices, API which is exposed on Web is called web services.**

Comment: Web Service is the standard defined by W3C, well documented service for the 3rd party software to interact through XML (WSDL/UDDI). Web API is the API over HTTP, not well documented, has it's own standard. And API in general is something that can or can not have internet access to talk to other applications and can have other protocols too e.g. API for system calls to talk your terminal/cmd in OS.

Answer (score -3):

Two things are very simple to understand,

1. API: It's an layer on application which can serve other application
   request locally.
2. Webs Service:Is an API which can serve request and respond over the
   network form remote system over the web or internet .

Note:
All Web Service is API's but not all API' is web services

Comment: On locally as well as on over the web