# I have a web api that consumes 2 webservices. Do I need to map every object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

Maybe this is a beginner question but I can't see the answer. So I'm build a web api that is going to consume 2 web services and the perfect case scenario would be the absence of mapping request and response objects. Is there anyway to share the same interface between the webapi and the 2 webservices?

This is in .net environment, webapi is being built in MVC.

Comment: maybe you can use that
[difference between a web API and a web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336347/what-is-the-difference-between-a-web-api-and-a-web-service)

Comment: I don't know if you understood, i'm not trying to map from the request to the json, but as soon as I receive the object from the webservice it is required to map(?)

Comment: Hi @whitecpt, can you show your code? Or at least a sample of it?

Comment: It's several classes, but I can explain an example.

So in the webservice side I create a project where I hold my DataContract classes, one of it is called Home. Then in the WCF service project I create the ServiceContract with one method GetHome that returns the Home DataContract object.

In the webapi side, first create a Home object.
Somewhere inside one controller I need to call the previous webservice. 
I start by opening using 'using' and then what I would like is to do something like Home home = client.GetHome(); But this doesn't work since both Home objects have different sources

Comment: Look into automapper. If the properties are all the same it can auto map them in one line of code. Then you can use one class for both.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid, because on complex objects I suppose it can be quite slow (?). But this is the way i'm going for.